# May many webviews cause my app to crash on my iphone 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

//The point

I gradually load many objects (UIWebView) to the memory and after a while it crashes. Please Help

//Details

I have a UIScrollView with horizontal paging, wherein each page (with a separate view controller) contains a UIWebView with disabled user interaction. At first only webview #0 on page 0 gets loaded and as I advance through the pages the app gradually sends requests to load specific data. Downloaded data stay in memory.

After I load about 20 Webviews from internet source, my app freezes and crashes. If I use a dummy html string stored on the device, this happens after I load about 50 webview. But the problem persists.

I fixed much of the leaks and am only left with Mallocs. Since the problem does not occur with low quantities of UIWebviews Loaded I assume that I have to change my code to say 3 webviews and reuse them. But I don't know if that'd fix the issue. I have developed several apps before which don't crash and this is a unique case.

I store pointers to webviews and some other elements inside every Webview (such as labels) in arrays. The arrays get incremented in count with every new page loaded.

I use xcode 4.3 and a jailbroken iphone 4 to develop. I turned off requiring signatures in my xcode as a result of which the app gets copied onto my phone yet fails to attach to process. I cannot debug on my phone. My app works well in simulator but crashes a while after I launch it on the phone by tapping the icon.

From what I am able to describe as so, what do you think might be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: if you wan't to create good apps stop using jailbroken devices, it's not really good if you cannot debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly having too many `UIWebView`s will cause a crash due to low memory.  I'm not sure what your reason is for having multiple `UIWebView`s, but I would follow through with your idea to reuse a smaller amount of them instead of creating several.

Based on your device not crashing when you use a small amount, I would say that the problem lies in the use of too many `UIWebView`s and not in a compatibility problem with your jailbroken device, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I too believe it's due to excessive UIWebview use.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit is notorious for its memory hogging. It mallocs large blocks of memory and fails before giving you the opportunity to release other resources. One `UIWebView` is bad enough. I've had this problem in apps with as few a 5 `UIWebView`s, let alone 50.

There are a couple of things you can try. One, if the web pages aren't too complicated, you could use a replacement view such as [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) to render them. If you have to have webviews, you could cache the various HTML contents and re-render using one `UIWebView`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, to completely abolish the WebView use. I use a ViewController for every UIView which currently contants a UIwebview. The HTML is actually very simple and could be reconstructed with an UIImage and labels. If I substitute every Webview with an Uiimage and 5 labels, do you believe there will be a great boost in performance?

Comment: If that's all that your webviews are showing, it will by all means be faster. Do consider DTCoreText (https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText), though, as it renders images and styled text directly from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use three UIWebView's for paging. Lets say the user is on page 2 (page 1 is the left page and page 3 is to the right). When the uses swipes to page 3, you could just display the web view currently on page 1 on page 3. You need to re-load the proper html when the user swipes between the pages.

With some caching of the web content, speed shouldn't be a problem once the stuff is downloaded.